# HashSet calls overridable method in constructor

Tags: java, collections, virtual-functions

It is bad practice to call overridable methods in a constructor (see [this link](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=215)). This will always call the method defined in the class and not a derived class' method. In Java's [`HashSet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.%3Cinit%3E%28java.util.Collection%29) there is a constructor that accepts a `Collection`. This method delegates to the `addAll` method. My question is why won't this break any derived classes of `HashSet`.

> Constructs a new set containing the elements in the specified collection. The HashMap is created with default load factor (0.75) and an initial capacity sufficient to contain the elements in the specified collection.
>   Parameters:
>   c the collection whose elements are to be placed into this set
>   Throws:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException if the specified collection is null

```
public HashSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    map = new HashMap<E,Object>(Math.max((int) (c.size()/.75f) + 1, 16));
    addAll(c);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that it *does* break subclasses, potentially. It's easy to show that:

BrokenSet.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BrokenSet<E> extends HashSet<E> {
    private final List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();

    public BrokenSet(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        super(c);
    }

    @Override public boolean add(E item) {
        if (super.add(item)) {
            list.add(item);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<String> strings = Arrays.asList("x", "y");
        Set<String> set = new BrokenSet<>(strings);
    }

}
```

Run `Main`, and you'll get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at BrokenSet.add(BrokenSet.java:12)
        at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.HashSet.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at BrokenSet.<init>(BrokenSet.java:7)
        at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

... because while the superconstructor is running, it calls `BrokenSet.add` which expects `list` to be non-null.

Subclasses would need to be written carefully to avoid this being an issue. (You might want to look at what `LinkedHashSet` does, for example.)

Comment: Thanks, how is this acceptable practice by the standard library? Why wasn't it designed differently?

Comment: @BenjyKessler: I can't answer that part :) Inheritance is definitely a tricky beast...

Comment: Something like a static factory method that first constructs and then adds all?

Comment: @BenjyKessler: Yes, that would do it - but then each subclass would need its own equivalent, which is annoying.

Comment: More annoying than having to "carefully avoid this being an issue"?

Comment: @BenjyKessler: I wouldn't necessarily say that - but this will be my last comment, as it's not really what comment threads here are designed for, and I wouldn't want to answer for any of the Java library designers.

Answer (score 0):

As it's not the only constructor, just additional one added for convenience, then it's not that scary: you still can implement the similar constructor in the derived Set calling default superclass constructor (with no arguments), initializing your instance and then calling addAll(). Probably it's implemented that way because it was easier to do so.

Comment: Firstly, breaking something because "it's not so bad there are ways to fix it" is not such a good way to go about life.  Secondly standard libraries should be written correctly not easily.

Comment: You are free to submit a patch to the OpenJDK. After all it's written by people like you and me.